# asmack : Receiving custom IQ messages in PacketListener

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am using asmack library for an XMPP chat application. I have some issues in receiving few custom IQ packets.
This is my `PacketListener` code :

```
PacketTypeFilter filter = new PacketTypeFilter(Packet.class);
connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        Log.i("PacketListener : ", "Received Packet in General : "
                + packet.toXML());
    }
}, filter);
```

It receives some IQ packets, but doesn't receive some other IQ packets. But, the asmack library is able to receive and print all the IQ packets in the Logcat under the Tag "SMACK" and a prefix as "RCV (1): ".

Any suggestions to receive all the IQ packets inside `PacketListener` ?
Please, let me know if something is not clear in the question by adding comments.

Comment: Do you have an IQProvider configured for you custom IQs?

Comment: Can you please point me to how to configure an IQProvider ? Thanks. I am basically trying to implement this XEP: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0167.html

Comment: are you getting you solution ?? @Manjunath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could able to receive the jingle IQ packets using this code

https://github.com/bejayoharen/java-bells/tree/master/src/net/java/sip/communicator/impl/protocol/jabber/extensions/jingle

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a provider.

For example

```
myProvider yourProvider = new myProvider();
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("jingle","urn:xmpp:jingle:1",yourProvider);
```

So asmack listens for those type of packets.
yourProvider is your implementation of an IQProvider

e.g

```
public class myProvider implements IQProvider {

@Override
public IQ parseIQ(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception {
    //Parse the incomming call data
```

}

Then you create your own implementation of the IQ class.

```
public class YourIQ extends IQ {}
```

And finally

```
theConnectionObject.addPacketListener(new IQPacketListener()
            , new PacketTypeFilter(YourIQ .class) {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Packet packet) {//Do your stuff}
```

Comment: Can you please share the CustomIQProvider and CustomIQ classes you have written for jingle ? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Im glad I could help someone for once :)