# XEP-0167, libjingle_peerconnection.jar and my application

Tags: android, xmpp, libjingle

I am trying to develop an Android App which shall support audio with other peers.

The signaling should work according to this principle.
https://developers.google.com/talk/call_signaling

I have included the libjingle_peerconnection.jar in my project. And I can successfully recieve IQ packets from another PC application built with libjingle (by the xmpp server).

e.g

```
<jingle xmlns='urn:xmpp:jingle:1' action='session-initiate' initiator='john....@testing.stuff.com' responder='par.mueller@testing.stuff..com/Smack' sid='GUV3WncaSdoPhQFF'>
<content creator='initiator' name='Audio'>
<description xmlns='urn:xmpp:jingle:apps:rtp:1' media='audio'>
    <payload-type bitrate='32000' channels='1' clockrate='16000' id='103' name='ISAC' ptime='33'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='56000' channels='1' clockrate='32000' id='104' name='ISAC' ptime='33'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='128000' channels='1' clockrate='8000' id='105' name='L16' ptime='100'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='256000' channels='1' clockrate='16000' id='107' name='L16' ptime='100'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='512000' channels='1' clockrate='32000' id='108' name='L16' ptime='100'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='128000' channels='2' clockrate='8000' id='109' name='L16' ptime='100'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='256000' channels='2' clockrate='16000' id='111' name='L16' ptime='100'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='512000' channels='2' clockrate='32000' id='112' name='L16' ptime='100'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='64000' channels='1' clockrate='8000' id='0' name='PCMU' ptime='50'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='64000' channels='1' clockrate='8000' id='8' name='PCMA' ptime='50'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='64000' channels='2' clockrate='8000' id='110' name='PCMU' ptime='50'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='64000' channels='2' clockrate='8000' id='118' name='PCMA' ptime='50'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='13300' channels='1' clockrate='8000' id='102' name='ILBC' ptime='33'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='64000' channels='1' clockrate='16000' id='9' name='G722' ptime='50'/>
    <payload-type bitrate='64000' channels='2' clockrate='16000' id='119' name='G722' ptime='50'/>
    <encryption required='0'>
    <crypto crypto-suite='AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80' key-params='inline:6wTsrUisanoAvhiWgNDznyjZvO17Ex' tag='0'/>
    </encryption></description></content></jingle></iq></body>
```

After I have recieved the session-initiate+transport-info packets its time for me to create my own packet-info and send back to the caller.

I assume I should use the classes in libjingle_peerconnection.jar and extract the information I need. But how do I do that?

Comment: Are you able to receive this jingle IQ packet through PacketListener ? Which XMPP client library for Android are you using ?

Comment: Im using asmack, and yes the packet transfers works fine.

Comment: Do you know answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776461/asmack-receiving-custom-iq-messages-in-packetlistener ?